# ReactJS: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: update is not a function // child component unable to update state of parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal: Passing a function from parent to child that updates the values on parent component.

I've searched some other threads that were not using arrow functions that corrected their issue.  I figure it is some sort of binding issue but I'm not sure where...  This is sort of a dumbed down version of what I'm trying to do.

```
"react": "^18.1.0",
```

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

    const update = () => {
        setValue(value + 1)
    }

    return (
        <>
           {value}
           <Child update={update} />
        </>
    )
}
```

I've tried passing the function a few different ways from parent to child.

```
<Child update={() => update()} /> 
<Child update={setValue} />
<Child update={() => setValue(value + 1)} />
<Child value={value} setValue={setValue} />
... and so on
```

```
const Child = ({ update }) => {

    const handle = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        update()
    }

    return (
       <form onSubmit={handle}>
       </form>
    )
}
```

console.log shows update is a function in child component, and even shows the correct values to be updated - however when it is time for the function to be called I get that error.

FULL CODE

parent:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'

//Style
import { Container, Card, Button, Alert, Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'

//Authentication
import { useAuth } from '../../authentication/AuthContext'

//Navigation
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

//Components
import Navigation from '../../components/Navigation'
import Loading from '../../components/Loading'
import CreateHOA from '../../components/CreateHOA'
import MapHOA from '../../components/MapHOA'

//Requests
import { addUser } from '../../requests/addUser'
import { getUser } from '../../requests/getUser'


const Dashboard = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [database, setDatabase] = useState(null)
    const [view, setView] = useState()
    const [action, setAction] = useState({
        createHoa: true
    })
    
    const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth()

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const update = async () => {
        getUser(currentUser.uid)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('get user', res)

            if(res.data){
                console.log('user exists')
                console.log('set database')
                setDatabase(res.data[0])

                try{
                    console.log('check hoa exists')
                    if(res.data.hoa.length > 0){
                        console.log('hoa exists; set action/view')
                        setAction({...action, createHoa: false })
                        setView(res.data.hoa[0])
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    console.log('hoa doesnt exist')
                }

            }else{
                console.log('user doesnt exist')
                addUser({ uid: currentUser.uid})
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('add user', res)
                    console.log('set database')
                    setDatabase({ uid: currentUser.uid })
                })
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('set loading to false')
            setLoading(false)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       update()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {loading ? <Loading /> : <>
                <Navigation />
                <br />

                <Container className='white-bg'>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xl={12}>
                            <h3 className='white'>Dashboard</h3>
                            <br /><br />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    {action.createHoa ? 
                        <CreateHOA uid={currentUser.uid} update={update} /> : 
                        <>{currentUser.uid}</>
                    }
                </Container>

                <div className='footer'>
                    footer
                </div>
            </>}
        </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

child

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'

//Style
import { Container, Card, Button, Alert, Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'

//Components
import LoadingSmall from '../LoadingSmall'

//Requests
import { addHoa } from '../../requests/addHoa'

const CreateHOA = (uid, { update }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const nameRef = useRef()

    const submit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setLoading(true)

        console.log('UID', uid)

        addHoa(uid, nameRef.current.value).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            update();
        })
    }

    return (
        <Row>
        <Col xl={12}>
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>Action Needed</Card.Header>
                <Card.Body>
                    {loading ? <LoadingSmall /> : <>
                    <Card.Title>Create an HOA</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                        <p>Type in the name of your Home Owners Association below and click create to get started!</p>
                        <Form onSubmit={submit}>
                            <Form.Group id='name'>
                                <Form.Control type='text' ref={nameRef} required />
                            </Form.Group>
                            <br />
                            <Button type='submit'>Create</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Card.Text>
                    </>}
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </Col>
    </Row>
    )
}

export default CreateHOA
```

Comment: Your example code looks fine. You are probably doing something different in your real code. Since your stripped-down example (presumably) works, you will want to build from it back up to your actual code, checking for correctness at each stage.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :/

Comment: Not fun (at least not to me) but a big part of what we get paid for.

Comment: Good point.  Thankfully this is just a passion project rather than for my normal program gig.  Strange thing is I feel like I've done this same exact thing in previous versions of react. I've added full code if you've got some time.

Comment: It's just a typo. Change this `(uid, { update })` to this `({ uid, update })` in your `CreateHOA` component. React components receive *all* their props as one object.

Comment: After changing that - and adjusting my addUser request (also had similar issue) its working.  Thanks for your second pair of eyes my friend!  Forgot why I was doing it that way in the first place haha

Answer (score -1):

Use `this.setValue()` instead of just `setValue()`:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

    const update = () => {
        this.setValue(value + 1)
    }

    return (
        <>
           {value}
           <Child update={update} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: How is a copy-paste of the OP's example code in their question an answer to the question?

Comment: So you didnt see what i changed? this.setValue(value+1)

Comment: I did miss it. That being said, it's a *function* component. There is no `this`.

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans, Jared isn't the only person who missed that change (or is likely to in the future). Instead of just making minor changes to code and expecting other users to `diff` your code with the code in the question, please always _explain_ your answer. At minimum, draw people's attention to the code you changed. Please read [answer].